# Conditional Distribution of One of a Sum of Variables

Tags: probability

If $A \sim N (\mu, \frac{1}{a})$ and $B \sim N(0, \frac{1}{b})$, and $S = A + B$, then what is
the distribution of $A$ given $S=s$? Assume $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: It's stil Gaussian. See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution  However, next time please see how to ask the question properly.

Comment: Hi Boby, thanks for your answer, but I need to know what the parameters of the Gaussian are. I'm not sure where that is on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional probability density function is:
$$f_{A\mid A{+}B}(a\mid s) = \dfrac{f_A(a)\;f_B(s{-}a)}{f_{A{+}B}(s)}$$

Now you know what the distributions of $A$ and $B$ are, so what is the distribution of $A{+}B$?

Well, the sum of two *independent* Gaussian(aka Normal) distributions is a Gaussian distribution whose mean is the sum of means, and whose variance is the sum of variances.

Thus: $A{+}B \sim \mathcal N(\mu + 0, \frac {a+b}{ab})$

Put it together and determine the conditional distribution of $A\mid A{+}B{=}s\;$.

---

PS: assuming you are using the standard notation of $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2)$ for a normal distribution of mean $\mu_X$ and variance $\sigma_X^2$.